# Java: Read JSON from a file, convert to ORC and write to a file

Tags: java, json, apache, hive, orc

I need to automate JSON-to-ORC conversion process. I was able to almost get there by using Apache's ORC-tools package except that JsonReader is doesn't handle Map type and [throws an exception](https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/master/java/tools/src/java/org/apache/orc/tools/convert/JsonReader.java#L251). So, the following works but doesn't handle Map type.

```
Path hadoopInputPath = new Path(input);
    try (RecordReader recordReader = new JsonReader(hadoopInputPath, schema, hadoopConf)) { // throws when schema contains Map type
        try (Writer writer = OrcFile.createWriter(new Path(output), OrcFile.writerOptions(hadoopConf).setSchema(schema))) {
            VectorizedRowBatch batch = schema.createRowBatch();
            while (recordReader.nextBatch(batch)) {
                writer.addRowBatch(batch);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I started looking into using Hive classes for Json-to-ORC conversion, which has an added advantage that in the future I can convert to other formats, such as AVRO with minor code changes. However, I am not sure what the best way to do this using Hive classes. Specifically, it's not clear how to write HCatRecord to a file as shown below.

```
    HCatRecordSerDe hCatRecordSerDe = new HCatRecordSerDe();
    SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(hCatRecordSerDe, conf, tblProps, null);

    OrcSerde orcSerde = new OrcSerde();
    SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(orcSerde, conf, tblProps, null);

    Writable orcOut = orcSerde.serialize(hCatRecord, hCatRecordSerDe.getObjectInspector());
    assertNotNull(orcOut);

    InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.json.snappy");
    SnappyCodec compressionCodec = new SnappyCodec();
    try (CompressionInputStream inputStream = compressionCodec.createInputStream(input)) {
        LineReader lineReader = new LineReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charsets.UTF_8));
        String jsonLine = null;
        while ((jsonLine = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Writable jsonWritable = new Text(jsonLine);
            DefaultHCatRecord hCatRecord = (DefaultHCatRecord) jsonSerDe.deserialize(jsonWritable);
            // TODO: Write ORC to file????
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to complete the code above or simpler ways of doing JSON-to-ORC will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, I would use Spark / Pig / actual HiveQL to do this

Comment: Isn't a Map just like a regular JSON Object? Therefore a Struct to Hive?

Comment: cricket_007, this JSON-to-ORC conversion needs to be done as a part of a web service which already receives JSON data and does other things with it, such as archiving. So, doing this conversion with Spark/Hive jobs is not really an option for us (even though we used them for this conversion in other places) because it will require resending JSON data to those jobs as well.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't create a SparkContext within a web server

Comment: In my previous comment I mentioned Spark, but in fact we only used Hive queries to do this format conversion, so I am not that familiar with how to use SparkContext to do something like that. What Spark java classes would I use to do the conversion? Any code samples or links to JavaDocs will be very helpful.

Comment: Just the base SparkSession variable in Spark2 can read a JSON file into a Dataset object. From there, you can parse and convert the Dataset object and `write` it using a special `format("orc")` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing using Spark libraries per cricket_007 suggestion:

Maven dependency (with some exclusions to keep maven-duplicate-finder-plugin happy):

```
    <properties>
        <dep.jackson.version>2.7.9</dep.jackson.version>
        <spark.version>2.2.0</spark.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.jackson.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
                <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
                <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Java code synopsis:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Converter Service")
    .setMaster("local[*]");

SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

// read input data
Dataset<Row> events = sparkSession.read()
    .format("json")
    .schema(inputConfig.getSchema()) // StructType describing input schema
    .load(inputFile.getPath());

// write data out
DataFrameWriter<Row> frameWriter = events
    .selectExpr(
        // useful if you want to change the schema before writing it to ORC, e.g. ["`col1` as `FirstName`", "`col2` as `LastName`"]
        JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(outputSchema.getColumns()))
    .write()
    .options(ImmutableMap.of("compression", "zlib"))
    .format("orc")
    .save(outputUri.getPath());
```

Hope this helps somebody to get started.

Comment: I started out rolling my own converter using Apache ORC and ran into an issue writing out a list with more than 1 element.  I found this solution and had it up and running within a couple of hours without even having to define the schema.  I just hope the lack of a defined schema doesn't bite me later on...