# Spark 2.x stream/paginate data from Snappy to ORC file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I figured out how to use Spark 2.x to read the entire data from a Snappy file into a Dataset and then write that data to ORC format (see [Java: Read JSON from a file, convert to ORC and write to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290348/java-read-json-from-a-file-convert-to-orc-and-write-to-a-file)).

However, the Snappy files I deal with are pretty big (500MB-1GB) and cause my spark process to OOM.

I am looking for a way to stream or paginate Snappy data and write it in smaller chunks to ORC.

I tried using

```
Dataset<Row> events = sparkSession.readStream()
            .options(inputConfig.getProperties())
            .format("json")
            .schema(mySchema)
            .load(inputPath);

StreamingQuery frameWriter = events.selectExpr(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(outputSchema.getColumns())).writeStream()
            .format("orc")
            .option("compress", "zlib")
            .option("format", "append")
            .option("path", outputPath)
            .start();
```

However, the above doesn't produce any ORC files presumably because reading from Snappy file is not really streaming, so the use of readStream/writeStream may not be appropriate here. However, maybe there is a way I can expose reading from Snappy file as a stream?

Or should I use "select * offset X limit Y" approach to paginate data I read from Snappy file?

Thanks,
Alec